# Why does mutt hang when running gpg in tmux?

Tags: tmux, mutt, gpg, gpg-agent

I run `mutt` in `tmux` and when I run `gpg` to sign or encrypt, gpg shows a blank screen where I would expect to type my passphrase. I've straced gpg and it shows that it's hanging waiting on a socket `read()` (presumably from `gpg-agent`. What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short answer

If you are using bash, then Chris W.’s wrapper script is the way to go.  If perchance you are using zsh, then you can exploit the `~/.zshenv` startup script to set `GPG_TTY` from there, no need for a wrapper.  Since bash does not have a similar startup script (cf. [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files)), you’ll have to use the wrapper there.

```
export GPG_TTY=${TTY}
```

### Some background:  Interactive and non-interactive shells

The gpg-agent expects `GPG_TTY` to point to the tty from where it is invoked, such that it can display its passphrase prompts in a secure manner.  The [GnuPG manual](https://gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html) suggests putting the following in `~/.bashrc` (or similar):

```
GPG_TTY=$(tty)
export GPG_TTY
```

If you invoke mutt directly from your shell, this will work:  `GPG_TTY` will be set, mutt will pick it up and pass it to gpg when it needs to.

However, when you launch mutt via tmux’s `new-window` command or similar constructs, there is an important difference:  Before, your mutt was in a so-called *[interactive shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Interactive-Shells.html)*—that is, you had a shell prompt open and launched mutt from there yourself.  `tmux new-window` launches a *non-interactive* shell, since your shell is only needed to launch mutt and you won‘t be able to interact with it.  In this case, bath won‘t read `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` at all, since they are designed to set up your shell for interactive use.

zsh does pretty much the same thing:  `.zshrc` is read for interactive shells and skipped for non-interactive ones.  However, in zsh, [you can supply a third startup file](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Files.html), `.zshenv`, that is read for *every* shell, no matter whether it is interactive or not.  Therefore, if you set `GPG_TTY` from there, it will always be available, no matter in which way mutt is started.  And since `$TTY` is a shell builtin variable that always points to the current tty, you can avoid the overhead of spawning a `tty` process every time the shell comes up.

Answer (score 4):

I was launching `mutt` by running `tmux neww mutt`. `mutt` was inheriting the environment set in `tmux`. This includes `$GPG_TTY` which is different for the new pane in which I'm running `mutt` (or unset if not in the `tmux` environment). I wrote a wrapper called `gpgtty` that sets `$GPG_TTY` correctly for new panes.

```
#!/bin/sh
GPG_TTY=$(tty) $*
```

Then I launch `mutt`: `tmux neww gpgtty mutt`. `gpg` works correctly after that. FYI, this is all using `pinentry-curses` for `gpg` passphrase input.